# How can I decrease the spawn gestation time for a Broodmother Dryder?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

In the Campaign my group is running we have a Broodmother Dryder. It takes several hours normally for the gestation of impregnated victims before the creature inside emerges and matures.

I've been running over it with the others, but every method of quickening the gestation time that we came up with seems to be flawed or confusing, especially during combat.

How can the Broodmother's spawn growing time be reduced outside of combat?
 (preferably within only an hour).
How can the turns during combat be reduced for the spawn to hatch?
(preferably down to 2 rounds)

Comment: Where does the Broodmother Drider come from? I've been through a few books and haven't found it.

Comment: Looks like *Dragon* 298 p.38

Comment: Why does it take several hours? It looks like the impregnation works like poison. That should only be 1 minute between initial and secondary effects.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are indeed pulling this from Dragon 298 I think you might be missing the nuance of the description:

> "The poison injected by a brood mother is actually a tiny egg in a
>   fluid that ***causes rapid growth*** of the egg under the right conditions.
>   The bodies of creatures killed by a brood mother's poison burst apart
>   as a monstrous spider, ***already grown to maturity***, is born to the
>   world."

I added emphasis to the bits that seem to imply that it is instant. they aren't part of the original text.

In a nutshell, if you want to do this as an NPC, make it as fast as you want, the wording is there to support it. More spiders instantly in combat could be cool - though a broodmother can have a brood with her to start with (1-10 large and 1-6 huge so another 1 or 2 won't mean much.) But then again, it might even be cooler if Bob the Fighter dies an hour later and a spider bursts out of him like in Aliens.